# abbreviate() in an if() statement

Tags: r

I would like to abbreviate the `Land` column to 4 letters **if** `Import` is Less than (<) 5000000.

data:

```
> head(dataAgg)
       Land     Import Export
1   Belgien  455223422   5787
2 Bulgarien    6151445    115
3    Cypern    1683563     95
4   Danmark 1007626421   8810
```

I thought something like this would work:

```
 if(dataAgg$Import < 5000000) abbreviate([i], 4)
```

Answer (score 10):

You don't need an `if()` statement or a loop.  You can use a logical subset.

```
w <- dataAgg$Import < 5e6L
dataAgg$Land <- as.character(dataAgg$Land)
dataAgg$Land[w] <- abbreviate(dataAgg$Land[w])
dataAgg
#        Land     Import Export
# 1   Belgien  455223422   5787
# 2 Bulgarien    6151445    115
# 3      Cypr    1683563     95
# 4   Danmark 1007626421   8810
```

Another option is the *data.table* package.  Here we don't need to coerce to character because *data.table* updates factors with its awesomeness.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataAgg)[Import < 5e6L, Land := abbreviate(Land)]
```

which gives

```
        Land     Import Export
1:   Belgien  455223422   5787
2: Bulgarien    6151445    115
3:      Cypr    1683563     95
4:   Danmark 1007626421   8810
```

If you need to you can run `setDT(...)[...][, Land := droplevels(Land)]` afterward to remove the old levels no longer in use after the abbreviation.

Also, note that the default `minlength` in `abbreviate()` is 4, so we can leave that argument out.

Comment: Thanks but doesnt work.

  `> dataAgg$Land[w] 
[1] <NA> <NA>
26 Levels: Belgien Bulgarien Cypern Danmark Estland Finland Frankrike Grekland Irland Italien Lettland Litauen Luxemburg ... Ungern`

Comment: @JoakimBäcklund - I made an edit.  It should work now.  We needed to convert the column from factor to character.